# Android studio can't open the design mode of navigation resource file

Tags: android-studio

The design mode is stuck on loading!

I'm using the android studio to design the app. I want to create a navigation file in the app. but when I opened the file, it kept showing 'loading'. The design mode may have some bugs?

I don't think this is caused by the bad internet and tend to think that it's an Android Studio bug. It used to work fine in last month's Android Studio version.

```
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/homepage">

    
</navigation>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your navigation XML file is empty so I am not sure what you are expecting to see. The navigation design view is pretty heavy and can sometimes be bugged but it just visualizes the XML, you don't really need it to create your navigation system.

You can try "invalidate cache & restart" and "Clean project" options on Android Studio as they might fix the issue. But you probably should put something in you r XML file first.

Comment: i had restored default settings in the file/manage IDE settings. but the IDE still shows loading.  when i input codes in the navigation file there is no automatic code completion.

Answer (score 0):

Of course the navigation file doesn't have anything yet when it's created. The design view is loading because it's trying to find the dependencies to support adding navigation graphs in the design view.

You need to add the dependencies (Groovy)

```
dependencies {
  def nav_version = "2.6.0"

  // Java language implementation
  implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:$nav_version"
  implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:$nav_version"

  // Kotlin
  implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:$nav_version"
  implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:$nav_version"

  // Feature module Support
  implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-dynamic-features-fragment:$nav_version"

  // Testing Navigation
  androidTestImplementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-testing:$nav_version"

  // Jetpack Compose Integration
  implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:$nav_version"
}
```

You can exclude what you don't need. For example, I only needed the Kotlin implementations and feature module support.

You can check more in the [docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/get-started#groovy)! I hope the link keeps working!